# Background image set by jQuery reset after redirect

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to change my website background image (at body tag) when user click on a menu button and navigate to different web page.

I use jquery in _Layout.cshtml and doing like this:

```
 <body>
<div class="page">
    <header>
        <br />
        <div id="menubutton">
            <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Kitchen")" id="bg1">
                <img src="../../Content/Layout_images/menu_kitchen.png" alt="kitchen" /></a>
            <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Stock")" id="bg2" >
                <img src="../../Content/Layout_images/menu_stock.png" alt="stock" /></a> 
            <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Shop")" id="bg3" >
                    <img src="../../Content/Layout_images/menu_shop.png" alt="shoppinglist" /></a>
        </div>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(function () {
    $('#menubutton a').live('click', function () {

        // Get the background class from id
        var bgclass = $(this).attr('id');
        var temp = "url('Content/Layout_images/bg2.jpg')";

        $('body').css('background-image', temp);
        alert($('body').css('background-image'));
        // Set the clicked menu button color
        var menuclass = bgclass + "_menu";
        $(this).removeClass();
        $(this).addClass(menuclass);
    });
});
```

However, although the background image change when user click on the menu button, it immediately change back to the default background image set in css (Note: eventhough I dint set any background image at css, it will immediately change back to blank background after page redirect)

Any idea why this is happening? If not mistaken, jquery .css() suppose will change the css of the particular dom? Why it will still reset after navigate to other page?

Hope can get some help here... thanks...

Comment: You sure this path is correct? url('Content/Layout_images/bg2.jpg')

Comment: yes, the image changed, just it immediately change back to the default one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click on the button, you get redirected to a new URL and the layout file is reloaded. This means you need some method for persisting the background-image information when you load the new URL.

```
@Url.Action("Index", "Kitchen", new { bgImage = 'image url here'} )
```

And then in the layout file, write a js function ( inside **$(document).ready(function() {}**) ) to set this bgImage parameter as background image.

Comment: hi, do u think storing the background image and "hardcode" it at every view is feasible?

Comment: If you want to have a different background image for different view, then a better approach would be writing a javascript function that sets the appropriate background as per the URL of the page. This function can be called from $(document).ready(function() {}) and hence set the background image.

Comment: Hi, Thanks! I keep making problem more complicated, in fact just have to do as what u said :) But i get a very slow loading and the content of the view is sometime shown b4 the background is changed. Any idea how i can solve this? thanks...

Comment: To fix that issue, we need to set the background image before we server the page to the browser. That means, we need to set the background image at the server side.